# Combine GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, geojson

I have some separate GeoJSON objects, such as

```
 var fc = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
     "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
           "time": 1369786338000
         },
        "geometry": {
           "type": "Point",
           "coordinates": [19.026432, 47.49134]
         }
       }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
           "time": 1369786340000
         },
        "geometry": {
           "type": "Point",
           "coordinates": [19.074497, 47.509548]
        }
      }
    ]
  };
```

How can I combine it to make something like

```
var combine = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
       "time": [
          1369786338000,
          1369786340000
        ]
     },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPoint",
       "coordinates": [
          [19.026432, 47.49134],
          [19.074497, 47.509548]
        ]
```

I am trying to use [turf-combine](https://github.com/turf-junkyard/turf-combine), but I got the error such as

```
 turf.combine is not a function
```

when I try to combine the GeoJSON together. 
I already define my turf such as

```
var turf = require('turf-combine')
```

Thank you